# Why does my datastax Solr not index my new partition data?

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have 3 spark nodes and 1 solr node in one dse cluster.

The DSE search works when I search for existing data, but after my columnfamily receives new data with new partition key, then the DSE solr does not index the new data with the new partition key and it also does not index the new columnfamily.

Is it because the data is on several machines and solr only reads from one partition key not from the other?

Comment: What replication strategy are you using, and what options are you specifying for that strategy? What version of DSE?

Comment: In the past I used Simplestrategy with RF= 2 now I changed to networktopologystrategy Datacenter: Solr with RF= 1. I use 4.8.5-1. It now seems to work fine but I am not sure if that's the best strategy?

Comment: You would have seen problems like those in the OP with SimpleStrategy. NetworkTopologyStrategy with workload-specific virtual data centers, as you have found, is the right approach.